# Change the displayed price on shop and single product page for products with tag

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Ideally apply a 20% discount to all products & variations that have a given tag then have it properly displayed.

Right now I have a plugin controlling the actual price and I am trying to change how the price is visually displayed...

I have come up with this partial solution to change the displayed price in the shop and single product page.

Can anyone clean this up? It's throwing fatal errors but is delivering the desired effect.... Looking to change the displayed price of a product with a given tag on the shop and single product page.

```
2019-11-21T22:45:39+00:00 CRITICAL Uncaught Error: Call to a member function is_type() on null in */public_html/wp-content/themes/child/functions.php:325
Stack trace:
#0 */public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(288): price_sale_comforter('<span class="wo...')
#1 */public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(208): WP_Hook->apply_filters('<span class="wo...', Array)
#2 */public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php(1750): apply_filters('woocommerce_get...', '<span class="wo...', Object(WC_Product_Variation))
#6 */public_html/wp-content/themes/child/functions.php on line 325
```

```
function price_sale_comforter( $price ) {
    $product_tag_term = 'comforter';  // CHANGE TO PRODUCT TAG
    $original_price = '194.95'; // CHANGE TO ORIGINAL PRICE
    $new_price = '155.96'; // CHANGE TO NEW PRICE
    $percent_off = '20'; // CHANGE TO DISCOUNT PERCENT AMOUNT

    global $product;
    $product_id = $product->is_type('variation') ? $product->get_parent_id() : $product->get_id();
    if ( has_term( $product_tag_term , 'product_tag', $product_id ) ) {
        if ( $product) {
            if (is_shop()) {
                echo '<a href="'.get_permalink($product_id).'"class="ivpa_attribute ivpa_html">
                    <span class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><del><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>'.$original_price.'</span></del> <ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>'.$new_price.' '.$percent_off.'% Off!</span></ins></span>
                    <span class="onsale">Sale!</span>
                    </a>';
            } //closing IF is_shop
        } //closing IF $product
        if (is_product()) {
            $price = '<span class="dynamic-sale-single-product"><del>' . $price .= '</del></span>';
            return $price;
        } // closing IF is_product
    } // closing IF has_term 
    else  {
        return $price;
    } // closing ELSE
} // closing function
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'price_sale_comforter' );
```

Comment: You are providing a stack trace, but is there also an error?

Comment: @snuwerd Yes there is an error, the stackoverflow formatting removed it, the error is visible in the post now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test the code here, but I'd start with a simple

`if (is_null($product)) return $price;`

after this line:

`global $product;`

Comment: Thanks @Snuwerd that stopped the bleeding, no more errors. Just, now in some of the emails sent out it still displays the original price, but I'd pretty much consider that a separate question. Cheers!